# How can I set database authentication in Mongodb - Is SSH Pipes better for MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, robo3t

I have installed MongoDB in my computer. I did't define any password and username for the installation. I can see everything with Robo 3T. 
Now I want to protect my database.
I have tried to set authentication for the database. I followed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ . It did not work.
I still can reach mongodb with robo 3t and see all information. 
I have also tried to start mongodb with --auth parameter. I have define a configuration file looks like 
And for starting mongodb

```
mongod -f C:\mongodb\conf\mongodb.conf
```

Mongodb has been started but, it did not ask any pass. And I can save simple data with Postman without authentication.

What I want to do:

1. Protect my database against Robo 3t. :))
2. I dont want to save any data without auth.
3. Building Nodejs connection string that include pass like 
   mysql://root:password@localhost:port/dbName

Here is my Nodejs index.js code

[image: indexjs]
this is my model.

[image: usermodel]

PS: I am very new in Nodejs and Mongodb.

EDIT: inside conf file
[image]

Comment: what's in C:\mongodb\conf\mongodb.conf? anything interesting in the log?

Comment: @Joe you can define a configuration file and run it.

Comment: I realize that, I was asking if you can show it to us

Comment: I have added image

Comment: the log should also indicate `authorization:enabled` in its options message when the server starts up.  If that's not there you may just need to restart mongod

Comment: @Joe, Mongodb work fine with this configuration. Butr it dont ask me any password or something like that. I can put user with Postman(its a program). And it don't ask me any authorisation. Everybody can push data, see data, change data. I dont want have it like that. I want to meke it secure.

Comment: Understood.  To make mongod require credentials, it must have authorization enabled in the running instance.  In order to verify the running instance has it enabled, you need to look at the log.